# Não fechar modal após evento $_GET

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou com dificuldades para manter um modal aberto após evento $_GET em um botão editar em uma tabela.
Estou utilizando modal em javascript sem bootstrap, quando chamo o evento ele carrega o modal com as informações para edição mas fecha imediatamente ao evento.

CSS Modal:

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
  }
  
  /* Modal Content */
  .modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
  }
  
  /* The Close Button */
  .close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

javascript modal:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

const botoes = document.querySelectorAll('.botao-abrir-modal');
botoes.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', event => {
    modal.style.display = "block";  
}));

span.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Botão editar na tabela:

```
<form action="index.php" method="GET" id="fomModal">
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
  <button class="botao-abrir-modal btn btn-warning" 
  name="idRefeicao" value="<?= $item['idRefeicao'] ?>" 
  id="myBtn">Editar</button>
</form>
```

Modal:

```
 <!-- The Modal -->
 <div id="myModal" class="modal">

 <!-- Modal content -->
   <div class="modal-content">
   <span class="close">&times;</span>
   <?php foreach ($manager->getInfo('refeicao', $_GET['idRefeicao']) as $c) : ?>
   <input type="text" name="descricao" value="<?= $c['descricao'] ?>" id="tags-input" data- 
   role="tagsinput" />
   <?php endforeach; ?>
 </div>
</div>
```

Tentei reabrir o modal dessa forma:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['idRefeicao'])){
?>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
</script>
<?php}?>
```

Mas o modal fica travado na tela!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Testou em colocar no action do form a URL q abre o modal? Pq ele fecha e abre novamente para o usuário.

Comment: @alexBaiaroski a URL é a mesma que chama o modal index.php, já adicionei também

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mudei minha lógica e utilizei uma função javascript no evento onclick do botão para setar os campos do **modal**, assim não preciso recarregar os dados do banco. Pois eles já estão na tabela!

Botão:

```
<button onClick="setViewRefeicao('<?= $item['value1'] ?>,
    <?=$item['value2'] ?>,<?= $item['value2'] ?>')"
    class="botao-abrir-modal btn btn-warning" name="idRefeicao" 
    value="<?= $item['idRefeicao'] ?>" id="myBtn">Editar
</button>
```

Função Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setViewRefeicao(value1,value2, value3...) {
        document.getElementById('myInput1').value = value1;
        document.getElementById('myInput2').value = value2;
        document.getElementById('myInput3').value = value3;
        ......
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Boa tarde,

Não sei se entendi muito bem, mas o seu problema pode ser o action.
O action padrão do navegador é recaregar a página novamente toda vez que um form é submetido, talvez seja esse o seu problema.

Na função que está enviando fazer o post, adicione

**event.preventDefault()**, provavelmente irá resolver o problema.

Comment: event.preventDefault() funciona mas sem post eu não obtenho o id da linha para função <?php foreach ($manager->getInfo('refeicao', $_GET['idRefeicao']) as $c) : ?> para carregar as informações no modal